# How to launch a window.xib file in storyboard?

Tags: iphone, ios5, ios4

I'm new to Xcode and building my first App, I want to incorporate a Twitter feed, my project is done in Storyboard but the Twitter feed code is with .xib, is there a good way to launch the .xib in Storyboard?

Answer (score 1):

There is no real need to launch the window.xib in the storyboard.  Just instantiate your view controller that is the file owner of your twitter feed code programmatically and push into your navigation controller.  It won't cause any problems.  The storyboard is basically an extension to the way screens were managed before.  You can have all you "scenes" in storyboard and programmatically push a view controller from outside the storyboard without any problems and navigate back again.

The UINavigationController is the key.  It only cares that it got a UIViewController.

Comment: Thanks for the response. When I said I was new I'm really new to Xcode... I've not used an earlier version than 4.2... Anyway, I've added a 'Navigation Controller' to my Storyboard 'Tab Bar Controller', I'm not too sure what's next? Here's the files for the Twitter Feed I have...